# How to print a 3x3 2D array using elements from a list in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I have wrote a code that displays a list.

```
import random

def Rand(start, end, num): 
    res = [] 

    for j in range(num): 
        res.append(random.randint(start, end)) 

    return res

num = 9
start = 1
end = 100
numbers = [(Rand(start, end, num))]
print(numbers)
```

The output is 9 random numbers in a list.

```
[[10, 32, 86, 84, 46, 91, 71, 52, 7]]
```

I would like to print random numbers in a 3x3 2D array.

```
10 32 86 
84 46 91 
71 52 7
```

Comment: Do you want to print the 2d array or put it in a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll skip the randomization part as it is not relevant to your question. In general, to split a list into `n`-sized chunks, you can simply slice the list while iterating the index in `n` steps:

```
numbers = [10, 32, 86, 84, 46, 91, 71, 52, 7]
n = 3
print([numbers[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(numbers), n)])
```

This outputs:

```
[[10, 32, 86], [84, 46, 91], [71, 52, 7]]
```

Or if you want the output to look like a 3x3 2D array:

```
print('\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, numbers[i:i+n])) for i in range(0, len(numbers), n)))
```

This outputs:

```
10 32 86
84 46 91
71 52 7
```

Note that the `numbers` variable in your question holds a list of a list of numbers, rather than a list of numbers. You should make the assignment `numbers = Rand(start, end, num)` instead without unnecessarily enclosing it in another list.